# How to find out if all variables are true or all are false?

Tags: javascript, boolean

How to check if all variables are true or all are false?

```js
var a = true;
var b = false;
var c = false;

if (a == b == c) {
  console.log('All variables have same boolean value.');
}
```

Comment: `a == b && b == c`.

Comment: @trincot what if I have 20 variables?

Comment: Then you have a code smell

Comment: `[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j].every(z => z == a)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a == b && b == c` This will be enough for you given example

**You can do it with [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) like this**

Here idea is to compare all the values with the first element of array using `every`.

```js
var a = true;
var b = false;
var c = false;

let arr = [a,b,c,false,undefined];
let arr2 = [true,true]

console.log(arr.every( e => e === arr[0] ))

console.log(arr2.every( e => e === arr2[0]))

console.log([a,b,c,false,undefined].every((e,i,arr)=>e===arr[0]))
```

Change it to function like this if it is going to be used lots of time

```js
let arr = [false,undefined];
let arr2 = [true,true]

function test (input){
  let check = (e,i,a) => e === a[0];
  return input.every(check);
}

console.log( test(arr) )

console.log( test(arr2) )
```

Comment: here, you need always to know the array in the callback, which makes it impossible to use the callback again.

Comment: @NinaScholz i agree with your point. but this is just an example in practice if it is frequently used changing it to a function will always be a better approach.

Answer (score 4):

You could collect all variables in an array and check with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and take the first element for checking against.

```js
const isEqual = (v, _, [w]) => v === w;

console.log([true, true, true].every(isEqual));    //  true
console.log([false, false, false].every(isEqual)); //  true
console.log([true, false, true].every(isEqual));   // false
```

Comment: Nice, and more succinct than mine.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let a = true;
let b = false;
let c = true;
let d = false;

const allTrue = arr => arr.every(e => e);
const allFalse = arr => arr.every(e => !e);
const allTrueOrFalse = arr => allTrue(arr) || allFalse(arr);

const trues = [a, c];
const falses = [b, d];
const mixed = [a, b, c, d];


console.log(allTrueOrFalse(trues));
console.log(allTrueOrFalse(falses));
console.log(allTrueOrFalse(mixed));
```

Answer (score 0):

If all values are true, this will return true and if not it will return false. Hope its what you want

```js
    var a = true;
    var b = false;
    var c = false;
    
    console.log([a,b,c].every( (val, i, arr) => val === arr[0] ));
```

Answer (score 0):

`if(x)` would return true if we have a non empty string, 1, and other possible values... Reference from Mozilla [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy). So we can't just use `if(value)` to specifically check for *true* or *false* *booleans*..

If there are 20 variables, [put them in an array](https://medium.com/@photokandy/es2015-array-from-rest-and-spread-449651a1851f) instead (use the `Array.from` or `...` operator)

The most reliable way to do this is check for [.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) value in the array equal to a specific value. That would automatically check that each value is equal to each other as well, along with the specific value.

```js
var truthy = true, falsy = false;
let arr1 = [truthy , truthy , truthy , falsy, falsy]; // Assigns variables into your array
let arr2 = [true, true, true];
let arr3 = [false, false, false];
let arr4 = [false, false, false, 0, undefined];

const checkAllTrue = (arr) => {
  return arr.every((val) => val === true);
 }
 
const checkAllFalse = (arr) => {
  return arr.every((val) => val === false);
 }
  
console.log(checkAllTrue(arr1));
console.log(checkAllTrue(arr2));
console.log(checkAllFalse(arr3));
console.log(checkAllFalse(arr4));
```

Answer (score 0):

In computer programming, there is a term called short circuit operators or logical operators, the are used to check if two operations meet a particular requirement instead of writing a bunch of conditionals (such as `if..else if..else` ). Short circuit operators or logical operators are represented as `&&` ( `and` ) or `||` ( `or` ). In some languages it is represented as `and` `AND` `or` `OR`.

`&&` ( `and` ) just as the name sounds makes sure that the both of its operands evalutes to true before executing a particular operation relating to that check

*for example*:

1.`true && true` evalutes to true
2. `true && false` evalutes to false  ( because the right hand operand is not true )

```
var a = true;
var b = false;
var c = false;

if (a && b && c) {
    console.log('All variables have same boolean value.');
}
```

The reason `&&` and `||` are called short circuit it is to avoid the below

```
 if ( a ) {

    if ( b ) {
         if ( c ) {
            coonsole.log('All variables have same boolean value.');         
         }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first variable here(or any variable) can be checked to know if all are true or all false. If the first variable is true, then check if all true and if the first one is false, then check if all are false.

For all true, `and of all variables` will also be true and if not then and of all will be false.

For all false case, we can `or all variables`, if the result is true then obviously all are not false.

No matter how many variables you have, you can follow this approach.

```
if(a) {
  x=a&b&c;
  if(x) 
      console.log("all true");
  else 
      console.log("neither");
}
else {
    x=a|b|c;
    if(x) 
        console.log("niether");
    else
        console.log("all false");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to validate if: a == b && b == c && a == c

Comment: `a == c` is unnecessary.  It would be true by inference